# Python/Kivy - Scrollview PC ok, but not in android

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, buildozer

I'm using [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) to build an Android app. In one of my three screens I have a StackLayout in a ScrollView. The Scrollview works perfectly on PC (when i run it with Pycharm to test before building it) but when i use Buildozer, and then try to scroll the screen on my phone, nothing happens but everything else works good and i can see the scroll bar. However, it just doesn't scroll.

Is that a Buildozer problem ? Or its a problem in my code ?

kv file :

```
ScrollView:
       size_hint: (1, .9)
       bar_width: 10
       bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
       bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
       effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
       scroll_type: ['bars']

       StackLayout:
           id: container
           size_hint_y: None
```

Python code :

```
def setup_scrollview(self, dt):
    self.container.bind(minimum_height=self.container.setter('height'))
```

Comment: Try binding at the same place, either in .kv or in .py.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

```
scroll_type: ['bars']
```

needs to be

```
scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
```

instead to allow "finger scroll" on an Android smartphone.